# why would calling loadMatchWithID:withCompletionHandler crash only on iPad 1 with iOS 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, game-center

I am getting the following error and crash on my iPad 1 - on iOS 5 only - though my iPhone 5S and iPhone 5 run the following piece of code just fine:

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchWithID:_match.matchID withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error)
{
 .....
}];
```

The exact error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GKTurnBasedMatch
>   loadMatchWithID:withCompletionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class 0x3f6d59c0

It may be worth nothing that I do not get this crash when running the iPad simulator.

Comment: That method (and class) was added in iOS 5.0. It should work on a device with iOS 5. Is it possible the iPad has a beta copy of iOS 5.0 (perhaps a version that didn't yet have the method)?

Comment: Oddly the 5.1 to 6.0 release notes show the method being added in iOS 6.0 but the reference docs show it being there as of 5.0. What version of the iPad simulator did you test with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `loadMatchWithID` wasn't actually exposed until iOS 6.0. I have the 5.0, 5.1, 6.0 and 7.0 SDKs available in my Xcode and can see that this method is not there in `GKTurnBasedMatch.h` until iOS 6.

The apple docs and iOS 6.0 and 7.0 SDK header `GKTurnBasedMatch.h` seems to be wrong with respect to when some methods became available.

There are also others that are wrong, that's not the only method tagged as being there in iOS 5.0 but is not there until iOS 6.0.

Here are the other two inaccuracies I found in that header with the same issue:

`- (void)declineInviteWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler`

`- (void)acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler`

Comment: If the docs are wrong (which appears to be the case), you should click on the link at the bottom of the doc page to submit the doc bug to Apple.

Comment: good call @maddy, I have submitted the problems to Apple and also updated my answer to include a complete list of inaccuracies with that header

Comment: Thank you very much for your response foggzilla! At least I can work around this by calling 'loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler' and then loop through all the match ids. Thank you again.